# What are the dangers related to keeping a human brain alive outside of a human body?

Tags: brain

I am interested in learning about the feasibility of keeping a human brain alive outside of a human body.

The question: **What obstacles do we need to overcome to be able to keep a human brain alive outside of a human body?**

The problems I am taking into consideration are:

- connecting nerves with an artificial skeleton, (no need to connect spinal cord?)
- delivering signals to the brain to avoid sensory deprivation?,
- keeping brain in a "healthy state" as long as possible,
- augmenting and stimulating brain,
- connecting the brain to external devices without hurting it,
- maintaining blood supply,blood transfusion problems (allergic reactions and hives, fever, hemolytic reactions, iron overload etc.)
- can a brain be in a sleep mode? keeping brain in a "work" mode,
- can a brain function without hormones?,
- can we copy a brain?,
- can we grow a brain? part of a brain?,
- regenerating brain, slowing down the process of brain degeneration,
- does the brain need bone marrow to properly function,
- maintaining cerebrospinal fluid supply.

I asked this question on Quora, https://www.quora.com/What-must-be-the-conditions-to-keep-a-brain-alive-outside-of-a-body

Comment: What dangers are you talking about?

Comment: What the dangers (with explanations) related to keeping a human brain alive outside of a human body. I want to understand them better. What are the reasons that we still cannot make a human brain live outside of a human body? I want a "big" answer.